Can the content of MediaWiki subheadings be automatically indented?
Question
When transferring documentation from mere .txt to MediaWiki's markup syntax, I've realized that all content beneath headings is flat. I find this seriously difficult to read, as do the others I work with. Take, for example, the undermentioned:
=== Heading ===

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    === Heading ===

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    === Heading ===

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

=== Heading ===

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

The indentation is removed. Consequently, I could use a list for this like I do when authoring Markdown documentation, but I'd rather have the rendered content reflect the source markup.
Meta

Please note that in the renderer (what you're seeing) StackExchange converts tabs into spaces. I'm utilizing tabs in that example.

Verified at mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&action=edit.

Asked here per recommendation from mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Communication/en-gb&oldid=6589987#Forums.



Paragaph text (<p>…</p>) is supposed to be flat, no matter, what is the level of document section it belongs to.
It seems that what you really want is a nested dictionary (HTML <dl><dt>…</dt><dd>…</dd></dl>). MediaWiki markup for it is: ; level 1 term : definition, :; level 2 term : definition, etc. Therefore, you need to convert your headings and following lines like this:

== heading 2 == \n text to ; heading 2 : text,
=== heading 3 === \n text to :; heading 3 : text,
==== heading 4 ==== \n text to ::; heading 4 : text.

You could do it using regular expression search and replace.
Alternatively, you could make CSS rules in your MediaWiki:Common.css ordering that a paragraph following heading, as described in this answer.

Not quite a dl anddt – the structure is meant to be moreso a <section> around headings and their body content. Definition lists wouldn't be semantic for this kind of stylisation. I should just do it in CSS and write the articles in HTML, I think. Thanks for the workaround too.
